# "-m32" option of gcc is not working in gitpod environment. (Bad system call)

Tags: gcc, gitpod

I am trying to execute "hello world" program in [gitpod](https://gitpod.io) environment in 32bit by using "-m32" option. However, I cannot get a good result "hello world". I can only get "Bad system call".

Here is my test.c (hello world program)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I only installed "gcc-multilib" to use "-m32" option

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

The below command is compile command.

```
gcc -m32 test.c
```

Then, I can get the result. (The process create core.* file e.g. core.2893)

```
gitpod /workspace/csapp-labs/test (main) $ gcc -m32 test.c
gitpod /workspace/csapp-labs/test (main) $ ./a.out
Bad system call (core dumped)
```

Here is my gcc environment.

```
gitpod /workspace/csapp-labs/test (main) $ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-Av3uEd/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

[Some people](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1219884) said it can be caused by seccomp. However, I can't find something wrong on my system.conf file (/etc/systemd/system.conf)

```
...
#CapabilityBoundingSet=
#NoNewPrivileges=no
#SystemCallArchitectures=
#TimerSlackNSec=
#StatusUnitFormat=description
#DefaultTimerAccuracySec=1min
...
```

Answer (score 0):

please see https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/7358

32bit is not supported as of now. You could utilize a qemu microvm for accomplishing what you want inside a Gitpod workspace.